# Objective-C: Instance variable for table view data source not being initialized

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm initializing the data source like so:

```
@interface SelectWifiViewController() {
    NSArray *exampleNetworks;
}
@end
```

and:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad: (BOOL) animated {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    exampleNetworks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"network 1", @"network 2", "network 3", nil];
}
```

I'm using the data source here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *tableCellIdentifier = @"wifiNetworkCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefaultreuseIdentifier:tableCellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, Test", [exampleNetworks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

which doesn't work; "(null) Test" is printed on each cell.

Edit:

Here is how I'm navigating to this view controller:

```
- (void) navAction {
    UIStoryboard *selectWifiView = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SelectWifiView" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [selectWifiView instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SelectWifiView"];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Several syntax errors in this line: "cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, Test [exampleNetworks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];". This code won't compile.

Comment: what is `Test` here

Comment: Ah, yeah, there should be a quotation mark and a comma after "Test." Must have deleted them by accident when formatting the post.

Comment: what is your number of rows in section count

Comment: I'm just using a constant––3––for testing purposes, because `[exampleNetworks count]` isn't working. I'm having no issue with cells being displayed or formatted; I'm just unable to use "exampleNetworks"

Comment: So what happens if you breakpoint on the two routines you show? (Or insert some `NSLog()`s if you prefer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such method as:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL) animated { ... }
```

You meant:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { ... }
```

Your current method is never going to be called, but if you eliminate that `animated` parameter, it should be.

I would suggest adding a breakpoint and/or `NSLog` statement whenever you suspect that a particular method is not getting called line you think it should be. That will confirm whether it's called or not, and if not, you can then start to consider various reasons why it might not be getting to that line of code (in this case, because the method signature was incorrect).

Answer (score 1):

Please correct viewDidLoad of iOS without animated as following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: Please read tuts to debug: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-is-exc_bad_access-and-how-to-debug-it--cms-24544